# Output issues with PHPExcel

Tags: php, export-to-excel

I have a web page where a user selects the amount of rows to be displayed followed by a button within a form that exports the data to excel.

```
<form method="post" action="">
     <input type="Submit" name="excel" value="Export" class="button">
</form>
```

I am able to get the data and put it into the excel file with the follwoing

```
if($_POST['excel']){
        $phpExcel = new PHPExcel();
        $styleArray = array(
            'font' => array(
            'bold' => true,
            )
        );
        //Get the active sheet and assign to a variable
        $foo = $phpExcel->getActiveSheet();

        //add column headers, set the title and make the text bold
        $foo->setCellValue("A1", "Nombre")
            ->setCellValue("B1", "Paterno")
            ->setCellValue("C1", "Pkey")
            ->setCellValue("D1", "Telefono")
            ->setCellValue("E1", "Ciudad")
            ->setCellValue("F1", "Used")
            ->setTitle("Contactos Encuestas")
            ->getStyle("A1:F1")->applyFromArray($styleArray);

        $xlsRow = 1;
        foreach ($rows as $column) {
            $foo->setCellValue("A".$xlsRow++, $column[2])
                ->setCellValue("B".$xlsRow++, $column[3])
                ->setCellValue("C".$xlsRow++, $column[0])
                ->setCellValue("D".$xlsRow++, $column[1])
                ->setCellValue("E".$xlsRow++, $column[5])
                ->setCellValue("F".$xlsRow++, $column[4]);
        }

        header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"ENcuestas_Contactos.xls\"");
        header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");

        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($phpExcel, "Excel5");
        $objWriter->save("php://output");
        $phpExcel->disconnectWorksheets();
        unset($phpExcel);
    }
```

This kinda works, the issue is that weird text allong with the webpage elements such as buttons and images get put onto the excel file.

What could be the issue?

is there a setting i'm missing?

Comment: Show an example of the $rows array that is being passed through, and what charset are you using?

Comment: Do you stop php processing after outputting the excel file?

Comment: `weird text` isn't much of a description for us to work with, can you give at least a little bit of indication of what you mean?

Comment: @MarkBaker the issue is not with the data from the array, i get the desired result there. The issue is that web page elements creep up on the excel file.  The text is like so `Џࡱက;     !"#$%'()*+,-./0123456789:;>?@ş+'ٰ@Hh 䄀Untitled SpreadsheetUnknown CreatorUnknown Creator@붣M΁@붣M΁`

Comment: If the web page elements creep in.... will the file actually load in MS Excel?

Comment: @MarkBaker  yea the file loads with an error and it actually mentions that the CSS file is missing. I get the correct amount of data though (in the test is 10 rows)

Comment: So if you open the file in a text editor, what does it actually look like? (especially at the end) Because there shouldn't be any CSS in an xls file

Comment: @MarkBaker if I open it up in a text editor I see the same HTML code of my webpage.  

Could this be because im outputting the download file to a single webpage?

Comment: Then the chances are that @Maerlyn is right - you're continuing to echo your normal HTML which will also then be written to php://output and corrupt the xls file - terminate your script after `$objWriter->save("php://output");`

Comment: @MarkBaker if i add `exit` after the `$objWriter->save("php://output");` it all goes to hell, the excel file no longer has any data from my array

Comment: Does it have the heading row?

Comment: @MarkBaker I dont understand :S you mean if Im I still have this:  
 `header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"ENcuestas_Contactos.xls\"");  
  header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");`

I do i have  
`header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"ENcuestas_Contactos.xls\"");
            header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");

            $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($phpExcel, "Excel5");
            $objWriter->save("php://output");
exit;`

Comment: I mean, do your titles appear in the worksheet? Is it only the data rows that are missing?

Comment: @MarkBaker if i put the `exit` i get only the garbled text without the xit i get the titles and data fine plus the HTML buttons and additional stuff

Comment: The "garbled text" is the binary Excel file itself: can you open it in MS Excel?

Comment: Sorry, Meant to say it shows in excel in just one column all with garble text like the one i posted before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out why I was getting HTML elements in the excel file.

I had the PHP code within the HTML.

Put the PHP Code outside the `<html>` code and voilà my excel file displayed without any issues.